# Why do regexes function differently in dplyr v. grep()

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I would like to select a few variables from my data frame and thought I could do something like this:

```
var1<-rnorm(10)
var2<-rnorm(10)
var3<-rnorm(10)
var4<-rnorm(10)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  select(ends_with('[2-3]'))
```

But that returns nothing. So I compared how this works with grep() and this works fine.

```
test<-seq(1,10,1)
grep('[2-3]', test)
```

Why doesn't `ends_with()` implement a regex interpretation similar to `grep()`. What am I missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can solve the problem by using `matches` from `tidyselect`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  select(matches('[2-3]')) #or '[23]'
#output
          var2        var3
1   1.51178117  0.91897737
2   0.38984324  0.78213630
3  -0.62124058  0.07456498
4  -2.21469989 -1.98935170
5   1.12493092  0.61982575
6  -0.04493361 -0.05612874
7  -0.01619026 -0.15579551
8   0.94383621 -1.47075238
9   0.82122120 -0.47815006
10  0.59390132  0.41794156
```

> matches(): matches a regular expression

all the other `select_helpers` use literal strings.

EDIT: as per comment by @James:

In order to ensure the regex only picks up the numbers at the end of the variable, you should use the expression `'[2-3]$'` where `$` denotes the end of string.

```
df %>% 
  select(matches('[2-3]$'))
```

Comment: In order to ensure it only picks up the numbers at the end of the variable, you should use the expression `[2-3]$`